# Classify all ring homomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm getting that the only homomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ are:

1.) trivial homomorphism

2.) If we assume $\phi(1,0,0)=0$, then

$\phi(0,1,0)=0$ and $\phi(0,0,1)=1$

or $\phi(0,0,1)=0$ and $\phi(0,1,0)=1$

or $\phi(0,0,1)=n$ and $\phi(0,1,0)=-n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$

or $\phi(0,0,1)=n$ and $\phi(0,1,0)=-n+1$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$

3.) and similar results if we assume $\phi(0,1,0)=0$

4.) and similar results if we assume $\phi(0,0,1)=0$

Are these the only homomorphisms?

Comment: Are these all homomorphisms of rings?

Comment: You do seem to have started out well by (presumably) using the fact that a ring homomorphism must satisfy $f((1,1,1))=1$, $f((1,1,1))=f((1,0,0))+f((0,1,0))+f((0,0,1))$ and $f((1,0,0))^2=f((1,0,0))$ [and similar constraints for values at $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$]. But those last two OR-clauses worry me.

Comment: @Lahtonen I used the fact that $\phi(1,1,1)$ has to be either 1 or 0, and if we assume $\phi(1,0,0)=0$, then $\phi(1,1,1)=\phi(0,1,0)+\phi(0,0,1)$, so if $\phi(1,1,1)=0$, why couldn't we have $\phi(0,1,0)=n$ and $\phi(0,0,1)=-n$?

Comment: Does your definition of ring include a multiplicative unit? If so, don't forget that homomorphisms must have $\varphi(1,1,1) = 1$. (if you use a different definition of "ring", then this statement doesn't apply)

Comment: $$\phi((0,1,0))^2=\phi((0,1,0)^2)=\phi((0,1,0)).$$ What does this tell you about possible choices of $n=\varphi((0,1,0))$?

Comment: Oh, I see. My bad lol. Thank you for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}^3$ has three generators.  Each can be sent to $1$, $-1$, or $0$.  (Can't send one to $n$ because $\varphi(ab) = n a b \neq n a n b = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$.)  Use the same idea to see you can't send a generator to $1$ and another to $-1$ (because $(0,0,0) \not \cong -1$).  This doesn't leave many options for a homomorphism.